# Why facebook app user-id is different among different apps?

Tags: facebook

Why facebook app user-id is different among different apps?

For exmaple, **app1** server get user1 information by access token, **app2** server get user1 information, too, But the user-id in app1 is different from that in app2. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question itself answers the question when you used the term "*app user-id*". The userid that we used to get earlier was a common user-id (facebook id basically it was) but now [v2.0](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog) onwards the userd id you get is an **app-specific** user-id which is unique to an app.

This is done so that an app cannot just distribute the user ids and anyone can use them. Only the app requesting can use these ids.

Learn more about app-scored user ids [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading/#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids).